# How to count the amount of triggers in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for a WordPress plugin:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    $('.wpcf7-field-groups').on('wpcf7-field-groups/change', function() {
        var $groups = $(this).find('.group-index');

        // Set index each time user adds a new field on front-end
        $groups.each(function() {
            $(this).text($groups.index(this) + 1);
        } );
});
```

Which dynamically sets a "number" each time a user adds a row. So like this:

```
<span class="group-index">1</span>
<span class="group-index">2</span>
<span class="group-index">3</span>
.... etc
```

But what I would like is to do is to use the row "count" as a variable. What I tried:

```
counter = $groups.index(this) + 1);
console.log(counter)
```

But then the output each time the user fires the button is this:

```
1

1
2

1
2
3
```

What I want to see is this:

```
1
2
3
```

How can I modify my code to do this?

Comment: The question is not really clear, what is exactly your output? You're cycling through each element every time you add one more.

Comment: [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) callback takes `index`, `element` as arguments, you can just use the index argument instead of using `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your

```
$groups.each(function() {
         $(this).text($groups.index(this) + 1);
     });
```

with

```
$groups.last().text($groups.length);
```

So that instead of changing the numbers of all elements, you're just updating the last one.

Comment: Great!! This is what I was looking for. The problem only now is, that the first element starts at 2, instead of 1

Comment: Ah yeah, you don't need the +1 when using `length`, my bad :) I'm fixing the answer.